# Convert Object [,] to String

Tags: c#

I have a problem here. I want to convert object [,] to string so I can get the value of that array. So here I want to get cell index of my excel sheet using EPPlus. I want to show the cell index into listBox. How can I fix it ?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in JadwalisiGV.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= endrow; i++)
    {
        if (data.Cells[i, 2].Value != null && data.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString().Contains(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
        {
            object[,] valueArray = data.Cells.GetValue<object[,]>();            
            listBox1.Items.Add(valueArray.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get in listBox is

> Object[,] Array

The output I want, such as

> [2,3] [4,3] etc

Comment: what is your expected output? what have you tried?

Comment: You should include more of your code, or at least a small example of what you are attempting, what you expect as the output, and what your actual output is. Please also take some time and read through the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: I am sorry. I've edited my code above@M.kazemAkhgary @gmiley

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the whole set like this:

```
    var stringsArray= new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < valueArray.Count(0); i++) //Get the length of first Dimension
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < valueArray.Count(1); j++) //Get the length of second Dimension
        {
            stringsArray.Add(valueArray[i, j].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to flatten you 2D array, you need to loop on each item like this:

```
        object[,] obj = new object[,] { { "string", "vars" }, { "foo", "bar" } };
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            strings.Add(item.ToString());
        }
```